# How to delete dynamically added row using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to put a 'Delete' button after each of the row of my table.The delete button should function in such a way that it should only get activated when a new row is added. And if out of two rows one row is deleted the delete button of the existing row should also get deactivated.Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```js
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+)$/;
var cindex = 0;
$(document).on('click','.Buttons', function(e) {
  var count = $('table tr:last input:text').filter((_,el) => el.value.trim() == "").length;
  if(count || !$('select:last').val()){
    alert("Please fill all the fields in the current row");
    return false;
  }
    var $tr    = $('#dataTable tbody tr:last');
    var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
    cindex++;
    $clone.find(':input').not('select').val('').attr('disabled', true);
    $clone.attr('id', 'id'+(cindex) ); //update row id if required
    //update ids of elements in row
    $clone.find("*").each(function() {
            var id = this.id || "";
            if(id != ""){

            var match = id.match(regex) || [];
            if (match.length == 2) {
                this.id = match[1] + (cindex);
            }
            }
    });
    $tr.after($clone);
}); 
  /*`For delete button*/
$(document).on("click", '.DeleteButton', function() {
     $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
/*for enable field*/

 $(document).on("click", '.DeleteButton', function() {
     $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" class="graphtable">
  <thead>

    <tr>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%"></td>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr id="id01" name="row">

      <td>
    <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField()" >
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="GDS">Guides</option>
          <option value="LOF">Latest Offers</option>
          <option value="TEM">Templates</option>
          <option value="VID">Videos</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="85" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input  id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="15" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />

      </td>
      <td>
      <input tabindex="6" id="Button4" value="Delete Row" disabled="true" class="DeleteButton" name="Button4" type="button" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>  
        <div class="buttonarea">
  <ul>
    <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button3" value="Add New Row" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" /></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the count of rows in the table on every 'Add New Row' button and 'Delete Row' button click   by:

```
var Count = $('#dataTable tr').length;
```

Then using the value of `Count` you can enable/disable the delete button e.g

```
if(Count < 2 )
//code to disable
else
//code to enable
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked. :). Just a small edit in your answer. Instead of applying condition as if(Count < 2 ) it should be if(Count == 2 ) as the value will be always two for the first row in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get your question right, but I would try to do it like so:

I would handle this over a class namend 'active'. You also can give this class a disabled style. Also I would toggle the show/hide function of jquery if the button was clicked. And if one button is the last man standing - I would hide all. So it cant be clicked anymore. You can also ignore the 'active'-Class if you juste need to show/hide the buttons. The buttons should have a specific class 'del-btn'.

Note: Class 'active' is just for showing the button but disable/enable. Show/hide is for 'removing' the button.

```````````````````````````
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+)$/;
var cindex = 0;
$(document).on('click','.Buttons', function(e) {
  var count = $('table tr:last input:text').filter((_,el) => el.value.trim() == "").length;
  if(count || !$('select:last').val()){
    alert("Please fill all the fields in the current row");
    return false;
  }
 var $tr    = $('#dataTable tbody tr:last');
 var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
 cindex++;
 $clone.find(':input').not('select').val('').attr('disabled', true);
 $clone.attr('id', 'id'+(cindex) ); //update row id if required
 //update ids of elements in row
 $clone.find("*").each(function() {
        var id = this.id || "";
        if(id != ""){

        var match = id.match(regex) || [];
        if (match.length == 2) {
            this.id = match[1] + (cindex);
        }
        }
});

// If you want to activate ALL buttons:
$('.del-btn').addClass('active');

// If just the added row should be active:
$clone.find('.del-btn').addClass('active');

$(".del-btn").show();

$tr.after($clone);
}); 
  /*`For delete button*/
$(document).on("click", '.DeleteButton', function() {
     if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
        // removing is allowed
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        // Now you can check, if the rest should be shown or not
        var btns = $('.del-btn').length; // count the buttons in the dom
        if(btns>0){
            if(btns == 1){
               $(".del-btn").hide();
            }else{
               $(".del-btn").show();
            }
        }
     }else{
        // removing is disallowed
     }

    });
``````````````````````````for enable field``````````````````````



 $(document).on("click", '.DeleteButton', function() {
     $(this).closest("tr").remove();

 });
```````````````````````````

Comment: Using this my 'Select' function is not working by which if i change the value of 'select' the corresponding field should get enabled